# Python на сервере

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование

я нуб в веб, подскажите как я могу добавить python в свой проект, на php, а также как я могу добавить туда модуль Translate, и обмениваться информацией с php?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Можете веб-сервис сделать на `Flask` на питоне и общаться с ним как хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уважаемые автор вопроса и автор ответа.

Не могу не отметить, что вопрос - по правилам сайта - задан низкокачественно. Автор не описывает конкретную ситуацию, которая у него имеется.

Тем не менее, я рискну ответить на вопрос другим образом.

Пускай у нас есть проект на PHP - просто для определенности. И мы хотим, не сильно меняя этот проект, добавить в него новую функциональность. Используя при этом другой язык программирования, например, python.

Сделать это можно. Я бы оставил на php *вызовы* функций, (например, через REST API), а сами функции написал при этом в микросервисной архитектуре, на любом языке программирования.

ТОгда мы получаем такую схему: вот у нас есть большой сайт.В том месте, где нужен вызов функции на "не основном" языке програмирования,  мы формируем HTTP - запрос, в параметрах которого лежат аргументы вызываемой функции, и обращаемся к "маленькому http-серверу",который есть где-то "сбоку" и предназначен именно для того, чтобы обслуживать такие внутренние вызовы. Внутренние - значит, в пределах логики работы "внутренностей" основного сайта.

Из PHP такой вызов может выглядетьп римерно так:

```
    $data = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ApiFunction1/?id='.$req);
```

Здесь я передал некий id, а в ответ получил данные - например, строку или json, и могу дальше в коде использовать полученное значение. САм же процесс получения данных  по id произошел вне php И мог быть сделан на другом языке программирования.

Эта схема довольно полулярна, можно погуглить на тему микросервисной архитектуры.

Собственно,в комментариях вам CrazyElf предлагал именно это, я просто написал расширенное объяснение этой схемы.

Comment: Спасибо! Благодарен